# Creating a system preferences-like key mapping interface

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield, nstextview

I need to create a key mapping UI similar to the one found in system preferences keyboard shortcuts.  I've looked at NSTextField, which has exactly the interface I'm looking for but not the key events.  If I switch the class for NSTextView it doesn't seem to display a cursor or the focus ring.  Could someone with experience in these things point me in the right direction?

Comment: This may have some of what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980187/user-assigned-key-equivalents

Comment: Thanks, if I had known about that from the start it would have saved me some time.  As it is I'm pretty close to a solution which exactly serves my needs, so I might stick with that.  I'll post what I did when I've finished.